# Center tap transformer

Tags: transformer

How can I convert a 113B13 transformer to a center tap transformer? Is like this, for example: 
- primary coil: 1 and 2 pins.
- secondary: 3 and 6, where 4 and/or 5 is the center tap?
Will this work?

[image: 113B13 pic from datasheet]

Comment: Why would you need a center taped pulse transformer? Show a schematics of this particular use.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič For the "Royer inverter".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect pins 4 and 5 together, and it becomes the center tap. Between 1 and 2 would then be the primary.

Comment: @Arttu:  Do you understand what ratio the center-tapped transformer will have?

Comment: @OskarSkog I will use for "Royer inverter".  I have 113B13 which is 1:1:1 itself. By using 3-6(with 5 and 4 as center tap) as a primary and 1-2 as secondary it will become 2:1 step-down transformer. So, if I need a step up transformer I need to increase the number of turns on the secondary. That I think about it.

Comment: That's correct.   Just had to check that you weren't going to do something stupid.